# Delegate won't execute function

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, pager

I have a view controller with a container view which contains a static `UITableViewController` as a menu. The parent view controller is part of a `UIPageViewController`.

Whenever the user clicks a row I want to call a function to perform a segue from the PageViewController. To do this, I added `didSelectRowAt` inside of the `MenuTableViewController`. - This function works fine, since print requests are being executed.

To call a function from the PageViewController, I tried to use delegate, **but somehow the function won't be executed.**

- RootPageViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.dataSource = self

        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "menuView") as! MenuTableViewController
        vc.delegate = self
        ...

}

func goToMap() {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goMap", sender: self)
}
```

- MenuTableViewController:

```
class MenuTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    weak var delegate: RootPageViewController?
}

extension MenuTableViewController {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath.row)

        if indexPath.row == 2 {
            delegate?.goToMap()
        }

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Edit: in viewDidLoad() of the PageViewController

```
let home = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homeView") as! HomeViewController
home.loadViewIfNeeded()
let menu = home.children[1] as! MenuTableViewController
print("Children:", home.children)
menu.delegate = self
```

```
class RootPageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIScrollViewDelegate, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    lazy var viewControllerList:[UIViewController] = {

            let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

            let vc1 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homeView")
            let vc2 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "timelineView")

            return [vc1, vc2]

    }()

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let transition = CircularTransition()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.dataSource = self

        let home = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homeView") as! HomeViewController
        home.delegate = self
        print(home.delegate)

        if let secondViewController = viewControllerList.first as? HomeViewController {
            self.setViewControllers([secondViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create another object for menuVc and assign the delegate to it , it differs from the 1 in storyboard , so  Inside `viewDidLoad` of PagerVC

```
let home = //
let menu = home.children.first as! MenuTableViewController
menu.delegate = self
```

Comment: Do you mean to present the the MenuTableController within the RootPageViewController? The MenuTableController is always displayed inside of its parent as a container the HomeViewController, it's just not in the screen. As soon as the user clicks a hamburger, it slides in.

Comment: how do you add the menu as container inside home show that code ? or you do it inside IB ?

Comment: I added a ContainerView to the HomeViewController with the storyboard - in this container I embedded an UITableViewController which is the MenuTableController. Additionally I added `@IBOutlet weak var menuView: UIView!` to the HomeViewController - but I've never used it.

Comment: you create another object for menuVc and assign the delegate to it , it differs from the 1 in storyboard ,,,,, try edit , i assume homevc is added manually in code to the pager so extract the real menu object from it which is the presented 1 and assign the delegate to it , your current code should print the delegate as nil for the above reason i added in answer

Comment: When I try to print `home.children` it returns an empty array, but when I call it later in code - there are children being returned. It seems that when the PageViewController is loaded, the children haven't been.

Comment: Print the children returns the correct children, but printing `delegate` will still return nil. I added the new code to the initial question.

Comment: how do you set home inside the pager ?

Comment: See edit, printing `home.delegate` inside of the pageVC will return the correct VC - but as soon as it's printed inside of another VC, it returns nil.

Comment: you should edit the delegate of the home vc which inside `viewControllerList`  that you assign here `viewControllerList.first as? HomeViewController` the one you currently  edit is on the fly it's not presented

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should use **delegate**:
*MenuTableViewController*

```
protocol MenuTableViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func menuTableViewController(menuTableViewController: MenuTableViewController, shouldGoToMap: Bool)
}

class MenuTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    weak var delegate: MenuTableViewControllerDelegate?

    ...
}

extension MenuTableViewController {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath.row)

        if indexPath.row == 2 {
            delegate?.menuTableViewController(menuTableViewController: self, shouldGoToMap: true)
        }

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }

}
```

*RootPageViewController*

```
class RootPageViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.dataSource = self

        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "menuView") as! MenuTableViewController
        vc.delegate = self

    }

    func goToMap() {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goMap", sender: self)
    }
}

extension RootPageViewController: MenuTableViewControllerDelegate {
    func menuTableViewController(menuTableViewController: MenuTableViewController, shouldGoToMap: Bool) {
        goToMap()
    }
}
```